# Order of operations when working with array index

Tags: c#, arrays, operator-precedence

Consider this loop:

```
int[] myArray = new int[10];

int myIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myArray[myIndex++] = myIndex;
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);
}
```

This yields:

```
1
2
3
...
```

Because myIndex is post-incremented, and the right side is evaluated first, shouldn't the array index 0 contain 0?

Can someone explain this order-of-operations misunderstanding for me?

Comment: Wow! I am shocked as well. Is this the same in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right side isn't necessarily evaluated first. Similar to:

```
foo.Bar.Baz = a + b;
```

In the above code, `foo.Bar` is evaluated first, then `a + b`, then the `set_Baz` method is called to set the Baz property to whatever is evaluated on  the right.

So in your code, if you break it into pieces, it looks like this:

```
var index = i;
// post-incremented in the original code means this comes after the line above,
// but not after the line below it.
i += 1; 
myArray[index] = i;
```

Answer (score 2):

first run:

```
myArray[myIndex++] = myIndex;
           *            *
           |            |
         zero          one
```

`myIndex++` gets executed after `myArray[myIndex++]`, but any subsequent calls with have the already incremented variable.

Answer (score 0):

The myIndex++ is executing before the value is being set because the array index takes precident so it knows what array index to set the value to.

Answer (score 0):

The `myIndex++` is evaluated first, followed by the left side and finally the assign operator, according to precedence

Answer (score 0):

The...

```
myArray[myIndex++] = myIndex;
```

...is equivalend to...

```
int tmp = myIndex;
++myIndex;
myArray[tmp] = myIndex;
```